# cPanel. Where is /var/named/example.com.db and others.

Tags: cpanel

When I try to add "add on domains", I get the error `Error from park wrapper: onlineprsuccess.com is already configured. Sorry, that domain is already setup (remove it from httpd.conf)`. I checked multiple threads over net and found to edit these files below.

But I am not able to find where to locate these files in cPanel.

```
/var/cpanel/users
/var/named/ del the domain.db file
/etc/named.conf
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
/etc/localdomains
/etc/userdomains
/etc/valiases/
/etc/vdomainaliases/
/etc/trueuserdomains
/etc/trueuserowners
/etc/vmail/
cd /var/cpanel/bandwidth/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access these by using the shell command option (SSH or putty). If you have the shell option enabled then there in the command prompt we can type `cd /var/cpanel/users` and then you can make chanegs to the files in that folder.

Comment: I am trying to access `/var/lib/pgsql/` but it give me `-jailshell: cd: /var/lib/pgsql/: Permission denied`

Answer (score 0):

Check and confirm that the domain doesn't already exist in `named.conf` and `httpd.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the instances of domain with the following commands via ssh

> grep onlineprsuccess.com /etc/userdomains

If there any, You can't create a duplicate domain until you removed it by locating the corresponding account.

> ls -l /var/named/ | grep onlineprsuccess.com

If you are getting any trace of the domain, Either remove it or rename.

Then restart cpanel

> service cpanel restart

Now try adding the domain. Let us know if the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

```
grep domainname.com /var/cpanel/users
grep domainname.com /var/named/  
grep domainname.com /etc/named.conf
grep domainname.com /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
grep domainname.com /etc/localdomains
grep domainname.com /etc/userdomains
grep domainname.com /etc/valiases/
grep domainname.com /etc/vdomainaliases/
grep domainname.com /etc/trueuserdomains
grep domainname.com /etc/trueuserowners
grep domainname.com /etc/vmail/
grep domainname.com /var/cpanel/bandwidth/
```

Also make sure that you have not added it as subdomain as when you create addon domain it tries to create the subdomain of it by default.

apart from above try to find if the same domain was created of the server before using below command :

```
gerp domainname.com /var/cpanel/accounting.log
```

updatedb &
once you comeplet the updatedb run below command.
locate domainname.com